# Test Class Cleanup Failure - Cleanup not working when running Specflow Selenium tests in a Virtual Machine (Azure Pipeline)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I implemented some Specflow selenium tests in a .NET project, and made them run automatically in an Azure pipeline in a virtual machine. It all worked well, but now I have around 20 test cases and, when they run in my local machine they all pass but if I run the tests in the virtual machine as intended it will fail and give this error: (Example)

```
 Failed Verify Monitoring Module Porto [1 ms]
  Error Message:
   [Test Class Cleanup Failure (Armis.EODREAM.QualityAssurance.Specs.Features.MonitoringModule.Map.VerifyMonitoringModuleFeature)]: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Stack Trace:
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.GetHookContainer(HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnFeatureEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnFeatureEnd()
   at Armis.EODREAM.QualityAssurance.Specs.Features.MonitoringModule.Map.VerifyMonitoringModuleFeature.FeatureTearDown()
   at Armis.EODREAM.QualityAssurance.Specs.Features.MonitoringModule.Map.VerifyMonitoringModuleFeature.FixtureData.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
```

I already tried limiting the threads and parallel executions in the xUnit runner JSON file, but nothing is working as intended with specflow.
This is my Hooks.cs class, where i initialize and dispose the driver before and after the scenario:

```
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public TestConfiguration envConfiguration { get; set; }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void InitializeWebDriver(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        var driverContext = new WebDriverContext();
        var driver = driverContext.GetDriver();
        
        string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        environment = "Dev";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environment))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT not set.");
            return;
        }
        

        Console.WriteLine($"Environment: {environment}");

        envConfiguration = ConfigurationService.GetConfiguration(environment);
        scenarioContext.Set(envConfiguration, "TestConfiguration");

        // Set global timeouts
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        // Register the WebDriver instance with SpecFlow's DI container
        scenarioContext.Set(driver, "WebDriver");

        // Create a WebDriverWait instance and register it as well (optional)
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        scenarioContext.Set(wait, "WebDriverWait");
    }


    [AfterScenario]
    public void TearDownWebDriver(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        if (scenarioContext.TryGetValue<IWebDriver>("WebDriver", out var driver))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tearing down WebDriver...");

            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
                driver.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("WebDriver successfully disposed.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while disposing the WebDriver: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Scenario Finished!");
    }
}
```

I really don't know what is happening and I am running out of ideas, so if any of you can help me I appreciate it!

I already tried to create a xunit.runner.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json",
  "parallelizeTestCollections": false,
  "maxParallelThreads": 2
}
```

And creating a virtual machine with more power (I have one VM with 4gb ram and 2vcpus and another with 16gb ram and 4vcpus).

The tests were always running fine before.